# Alter statement that includes foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

```
ALTER TABLE Class_T (
ADD COLUMN 'hostId' INT,
ADD FOREIGN KEY ('hostId') REFERENCES Host_T ('hostId'));
```

I am trying to add a column in a Class_T table and make it refrence a primary key in another table.  I am using phpmyadmin.

I keep getting this error when trying to run this.

```
Error SQL query: ALTER TABLE Class_T ( ADD COLUMN 'hostId' INT, 
ADD FOREIGN KEY ('hostId')   REFERENCES Host_T ('hostId')) 
MySQL said: Documentation #1064 - You have an error in your 
SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL 
server version for the right syntax to use near 
'( ADD COLUMN 'hostId' INT, ADD FOREIGN KEY ('hostId') 
REFERENCES Host_T ('host' at line 1 –
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Which error you are getting?

Comment: Error
SQL query:


ALTER TABLE Class_T (
ADD COLUMN 'hostId' INT,
ADD FOREIGN KEY ('hostId') REFERENCES Host_T ('hostId'))
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(
ADD COLUMN 'hostId' INT,
ADD FOREIGN KEY ('hostId') REFERENCES Host_T ('host' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the brackets:

```
ALTER TABLE Class_T
ADD COLUMN 'hostId' INT,
ADD FOREIGN KEY ('hostId') REFERENCES Host_T ('hostId');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple errors in your query.

1. No `'('` and `')'` braces are required around entities being added
   or modified.
2. Use only back ticks **`` ` ``** around identifiers. And they are optional
   unless the names are MySQL reserved words. Single quotes are for
   literals.

**Changed query**:

```
ALTER TABLE Class_T 
      ADD COLUMN hostId INT,
      ADD FOREIGN KEY ( hostId ) REFERENCES Host_T( hostId );
```